# PHP OOP confusion for noobie

Tags: php, oop, variables

I have a problem that's born of being a dyed in the wool procedural programmer who's here forced into using some OOP constructs in order to make use of a library I need to use. I am stuck unable to access variables- other than print them out. Let me illustrate:

```
foreach($html->find('span[class="given-name"]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

foreach($html->find('span[class="family-name"]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

The above will print out a long list of first names, followed by a long list of surnames. However I want to be able to access them together. For example I want to be able to say something like `$myarray["firstname"] = (*whatever is in $e->innertext*)` and also `$myarray["surnamename"] = (*whatever is in the next $e->innertext*)`

When I try the seemingly obvious:

`$x = $e->innertext;`

it crashes. I assume that's because I am passing a pointer to `$x` instead of a value, but how on earth do I tell it I want the value - in this case a part of a person's name, to be assigned to `$x`, or my array, or whatever the variable might be?

I am almost a complete neophyte when it comes to OOP concepts and constructs, so please bear that in mind. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Are you saying you want to take each name and store it in an array as you go through the foreach loop? What is the rest of the code when you do `$x=$e->innertext;`? Is it just preceded by `foreach($html->find('span[class="family-name"]') as $e)`? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: `innerText` is just a string, there's nothing special about it.

Comment: There is nothing after the $x=$e->innertext; because adding that line made it crash. All the rest of it is is a long list of foreach/echo's on lots of related data items, like address, town, state, country etc. There is no HTML to speak of.

Comment: What was the error message when it crashed?

Comment: Did you put the assignment in your loop? Did you remember to add braces around the loop body, since it's now two lines?

Comment: No error message, it just hung.

Comment: Did you check the PHP error log on the server?

Comment: Yes I added braces. I also tried removing the echo line so the $x assignment was the only following line.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea where the hosting company stores error messages. Is there a 'standard' location you know of?

Comment: No idea, maybe something like `/var/log/php.error.log`. Please post the actual code you're trying to run, rather than describing it in general terms.

Comment: I don't see any relevance to OOP in this question. It's just about XML parsing. If you use OOP for this or not is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I have seen XML documents and they don't look anything like this. XML documents seem to simply declare structural relationships. This code is a) executable, unlike XML, and b) uses object oriented structures such as properties. I' may be a noob but even I can see that far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your document is well structured and in order, this should do the trick:

```
$name=array();
$surname=array();

foreach($html->find('span[class="given-name"]') as $e){
    $name[]=$e->innertext;
}

foreach($html->find('span[class="family-name"]') as $e){
    $surname[]=$e->innertext;
}

foreach($name as $key=>$value){
  echo $name[$key] . " " . $surname[$key] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please put braces around your loop bodies, don't promote bad programming style.

Comment: I guess we should consider the case  #surnames != #names as well ?

Comment: Huummm. I didnt follow you birgire. Why we need to check that?

Comment: I'm just wondering about the case when `count( $name )` is not the same as `count( $surname )`.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. If so, check if they are equal will not fix it. If the elements are not even we will mismatch the names and surnames. Thats why I wrote the solution only will work if the document is well structured.

Comment: Jose - your solution at least does not crash IF I remove the 3 lines at the end that try to echo the results.

Comment: yes, I guess it's more of a possibility that the OP should consider ;-) But +1 for your effort.

Comment: Oh! A missing semicolon on the penultimate line! Bingo! It DOES work. Thank you Jose! And thank you all for your thoughts :)